# Maximum call stack size exceeded in WooCommerce

Tags: jquery, html, woocommerce

I've this HTMl structure here:

```
<li class="description_tab" id="tab-title-description" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-description">
      <a href="#tab-description">Description</a>
</li>
```

This is my JS function:

```
jQuery('body.woocommerce div.product .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li').click(function () {
    jQuery('a', this).click();
});
```

What I tried to do is to check if the tab was clicked. If this is true I will trigger the a inside of the clicked tab. But I'm getting an error when I load the page:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>           at String.replace ()
>           at Function.trim (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
>           at new a.fn.init (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2)
>           at n (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
>           at HTMLLIElement. (custom.js?ver=4.9.8:77)
>           at HTMLLIElement.dispatch (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
>           at HTMLLIElement.r.handle (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
>           at Object.trigger (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
>           at Object.a.event.trigger (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2)
>           at HTMLAnchorElement. (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)

Whats wrong?

Comment: The issue is because you're creating infinite recursion by raising a click event on the element from a click event on the element. `What I tried to do is to check if the tab was clicked. If this is true I will trigger the a inside of the clicked tab. But I'm getting an error when I load the page` Why would you want to do that? If you're trying to expand the hit area of the `a` element I'd suggest doing it in CSS instead.

Comment: In Wordpress there is a click function for the a element but not for the tab. So I don't want to click the text only. I'll also switch the content when the surrounded tab gets clicked.

Comment: As @RoryMcCrossan suggests, this is better solved by CSS. Easiest solution: set `a` to `display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%;` and add a span tag inside `a`. Then change all the old `a` styles to `a span`.

Comment: And whats with the click function for the a inside each tab?

Comment: The point is that this above is the standard WooCommerce code and I don't want to change that because of updates etc.

Comment: Again, you don't need to. Amend the CSS of the `a` element to fill the `li`. You don't need to amend the HTML or the JS.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works now. Working but a lot of code:

```
jQuery('body.woocommerce div.product .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li').click(function () {
        var description = jQuery('.woocommerce-Tabs-panel--description');
        var reviews = jQuery('.woocommerce-Tabs-panel--reviews');
        if (!jQuery(this).hasClass('active')) {
            if (jQuery(this).hasClass('reviews_tab')) {
                jQuery('.description_tab').removeClass('active');
                jQuery(this).addClass('active');
                description.hide();
                reviews.show();
            } else if (jQuery(this).hasClass('description_tab')) {
                jQuery('.reviews_tab').removeClass('active');
                jQuery(this).addClass('active');
                reviews.hide();
                description.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

I don't know if I can do this better.

Answer (score -1):

use `$(this)`, instead of `this`

```
jQuery('body.woocommerce div.product .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li').click(function () {
    jQuery('a', $(this)).click();
});
```

Comment: `$(this)` and `this` behave identically in that context.

Comment: You know that jQuery is the only right syntax for WP?.